# A confusing statement from "Berkeley Problems in Mathematics"

Tags: group-theory

This is from pg. 402 of "Berkeley Problems in Mathematics". The statement below forms part of the solution of problem 6.4.12

Let $\phi:G\to S_n$ be a  homomorphism between group $G$ and symmetric group $S_n$

> This homomorphism cannot map onto the entire symmetric group, since this symmetric group has a subgroup of index $2$, which would pull back to a subgroup of index $2$ in $G$.

Why would the inverse of a subgroup of index $2$ have an inverse of index $2$? Shouldn't it just be a multiple of $2$?

Answer (score 2):

No, it's really 2. Let $\phi:G\to H$ and $K\subset H$ be a subgroup of index 2. Then $\psi: H\to H/K$ is a surjection onto a 2-element set (a group in this case, since index-2 subgroups are normal.) The map $G\to G/\phi^{-1} K$ is the restriction of the composition $\psi\circ \phi$ to its image, so $\phi^{-1} K$ is of index *dividing* 2, rather than a multiple of 2. If $\phi$ is surjective, then $\psi\circ \phi$ is surjective and $\phi^{-1}K$ has index 2.